# Firebase - waiting for data from async database call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch some data from firebase with 2 database calls.
My strategy to get accounts only for 1 user is as follows:

- fetch all account numbers for logged in user
- new fetch call to get array of accounts (with all their data)
- dispatch call with full array

My firebase structure look like this.

[image]

My problem is that the second fetch call always finishes last.

```
export const fetchAccounts = () => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const accounts = [];
      const uid = getState().auth.uid;

      return database.ref(`users/${uid}/accounts`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
         snapshot.forEach((element) => {
            database.ref(`accounts/${element.key}`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
               accounts.push(snapshot.val());
               console.log('snapshot: ', accounts);
            })
         });
         console.log('Acc 1:', accounts);
      }).then(() => {
         console.log('Acc 2:', accounts)
      })

      // dispatch call with full array
   }
};
```

[image]

I am calling action from main file

```
  reduxStore.dispatch(fetchAccounts()).then(()=>{
     renderApp();
  });
```

Is it possible to wait for both database calls to finish and then call dispatch function with fully populated array? Appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `then()` doesn't return anything so the second `then()` will fire immediately which is what you are seeing in the console. The loop of requests however are *asynchronous* and haven't completed yet

Create an array of promises and use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) so the second `then()`  won't fire until the requests in the loop all complete.

```
export const fetchAccounts = () => {
   return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const accounts = [];
      const uid = getState().auth.uid;

      return database.ref(`users/${uid}/accounts`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
         const accountPromises =[];// array to store promises

         snapshot.forEach((element) => {
            // reference promise to pass into array
            const request = database.ref(`accounts/${element.key}`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
               accounts.push(snapshot.val());
               console.log('snapshot: ', accounts);
            });
            // push request promise to array
            accountPromises.push(request)

         });
         console.log('Acc 1:', accounts);// accounts should still be empty here since requests are in progress
         // return promise that doesn't resolve until all requests completed
         return Promise.all(accountPromises);
      }).then(() => {
         // shouldn't fire until all the above requests have completed
         console.log('Acc 2:', accounts);
         return accounts // return array to use in next `then()`
      })

      // dispatch call with full array
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The comments did help a lot to understand the logic :)

Comment: Keep in mind that if any one of these requests fails `promise.all()` won't resolve so you will need to add additional `catch()` for error handling